# Why does this need an explicit type?

Tags: haskell

I wrote a generic type to type converter in Haskell using classes as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class Convertable a where
    convert::a

instance Convertable (Int -> String) where
    convert = show

instance Convertable (String -> Int) where
    convert = read

main = do
    let result = ((+1) . convert :: String -> Int) "1"
    print result
```

But I need the explicit type `String -> Int` in order to get it to work (which kind of negates the purpose of having a generic type converter....)

Why would this type declaration be needed at all, there is just one possibility that satisfies the types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

convert is not the problem here, numbers by default are of type Num a => a, so the problem here is +1 you have there. You have to give it a concrete type.

Comment: Shouldn't Haskell still recognize that the only "a" that is type consistent is "a=Int"?Is there a reason that this doesn't happen other than it just isn't implemented yet (which is cool, I don't mean to complain), or is there something more fundamental that makes this impossible.

Comment: Haskell's type classes are "open". You can add new instances at all times. As a consequence, the presence (or absence) of instances never influences type checking. You have to provide a context that's unambiguous and thereby makes it clear which instance to choose.

Comment: OK, I get it....  If this worked as I indicated it should, it might compile today, then a few months down the road when another Convertable is added (perhaps deep inside some updated library), suddenly things would mysteriously break.  Makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can also just specify the type of `result` and ghc will infer the type of `convert` and of the Num instance for `(+1)`:

```
main = do
    let result :: Int
        result = ((+1) . convert) "1"
    print result
```